# Load Testing tool help which can send emails to 500 or more users

Tags: load-testing, web-application

I have to test a web application which sends emails to multiple users. I have to test it to send emails to more than 500 users at a time. Any tool which can create 500 users and send emails to them

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please suggest a testing tool which can help me send emails to 500 users at a time and what is the impact of sending emails on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a number of free and open source load testing tools](http://mailtestingtools.blogspot.com/) which could stress your SMTP server, for example:

- [Postal](https://doc.coker.com.au/projects/postal/)
- [xstress](http://xstress.sourceforge.net/)
- [Mstone](http://mstone.sourceforge.net/)

You can also consider [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which is a multiprotocol load testing tool supporting sending emails via [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler), it might be the most user-friendly option as JMeter is a GUI-based tool and test plan creation is pretty fast and easy. Check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to send sample emails to my email ID on Gmail by this example. Just one more question, instead of smtp.googlemail.com, what will be smtp address for my application which I am testing right now?

Comment: I don't know, you should either inspect your application email configuration your self or ask around

Comment: lol I didn't mean to say that you tell me what should be smtp address, I just need to know how can I check smtp address for my application. Your answer is enough that I should check my application email configuration. thanx

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider locust https://locust.io/ which seems to have a lighter footprint and be awesome at generating high loads quickly.  Seems the best of what I've been looking at lately..

Answer (score 0):

This site a little old, but it lists various SMTP testing tools and covers POP3 and IMAP too

http://mailtestingtools.blogspot.com/